# Why is my Linq query not updating the DB?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Wondering if anyone can see why i am getting the error "Row not found or changed." when i perform this LINQ query.

The row is there and the data is being picked up ok, but when it comes to update i am getting the error mentioned above.

```
aboDataDataContext dc = new aboDataDataContext();

        var orders = dc.GetOrderToAcknowledges;

        //Get the TWE Order ID and Store in DB.
        foreach (var order in orders)
        {
            int orderId = dc.amzOrders.Single(o => o.amzOrderId == order.amzOrderId).id;
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

            GetTWEOrderID(orderId, now.ToString());

            amzOrder orderUpdate = dc.amzOrders.Single(o => o.id == orderId);
            orderUpdate.acknowledged = true;
            orderUpdate.lastUpdate = Convert.ToDateTime(now);

            dc.SubmitChanges();

        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linq row not found or changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8851482/linq-row-not-found-or-changed)

Comment: Are you doing anything else in the context dc before?

Comment: yes will update the code above...

Comment: Did you tried to move dc.SubmitChanges(); outside the foreach loop?

Comment: Could you please specify which line is throwing an exception?

Comment: that would be `dc.SubmitChanges();`

Comment: @DaveHogan thanks for your suggestion, managed to work it out from that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out, looked into what DaveHogan said, and moved it around a bit also updated things a little...

```
var ou = dc.amzOrders.Single(o => o.amzOrderId == order.amzOrderId);
int orderId = ou.id;
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

ou.acknowledged = true;
ou.lastUpdate = Convert.ToDateTime(now);

dc.SubmitChanges();

GetTWEOrderID(orderId, now.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the designer shows **the exact same fields** for your entities like your database schema.

This error often occurs when there are changes in the database **that were not updated** in the entities.

For example a table column might be changed to allow for `null` values but the entities were not updated to recognize the change.